# Swift 3 filter array of objects with elements of array

Tags: arrays, swift

```
array1 = array1.filter{ $0.arrayInsideOfArray1.contains(array2[0]) }
```

Code above works but I'm trying to check if all the elements of $0.arrayInsideOfArray1 match with all the elements of array2 not just [0]

Example:

```
struct User {
    var name: String!
    var age: Int!
    var hasPet: Bool!
    var pets: [String]!
}

var users: [User] = []

users.append(User(name: "testUset", age: 43, hasPet: true, pets: ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]))
users.append(User(name: "testUset1", age: 36, hasPet: true, pets:["rabbit"]))
users.append(User(name: "testUset2", age: 65, hasPet: true, pets:["Guinea pigs", "Rats"]))

let petArr = ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]

users = users.filter { $0.pets.contains(petArr[0]) }
```

What I want is any user that has any pet listed in the petArr!

Comment: You still haven't explained what results your expect to get with the code you posted.

Comment: print(user)
    
prints: (name: "testUset", age: 43, hasPet: true, pets: ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"])]

But the result I wanted to get in this case would be:

User(name: "testUset", age: 43, hasPet: true, pets: ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"])]
User(name: "testUset1", age: 36, hasPet: true, pets:["rabbit"])]

Comment: So what you want is any user that has any pet listed in the `petArr`, correct?

Comment: Then please update your question to make that clear. Update your question to show the results you want.

Comment: @NikaE you should declare all properties of your structure as constantes and get rid of your IUO in all of them. structures don't require you to create its initializers.  `struct User {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let hasPet: Bool
    let pets: [String]
}`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

One approach is to update your filter to see if any value in pets is in the `petArr` array:

```
users = users.filter { $0.pets.contains(where: { petArr.contains($0) }) }
```

The first `$0` is from the `filter` and it represents each `User`.

The second `$0` is from the first `contains` and it represents each pet within the `pets` array of the current `User`.

Comment: The second `$0` is optional, writing `where: petArr.contains`is enough. 

Answer (score 4):

If elements inside the internal array are `Equatable` you can just write:

```
array1 = array1.filter{ $0.arrayInsideOfArray1 == array2 }
```

If they are not, you can make them, by adopting `Equatable` protocol and implementing:

```
func ==(lhs: YourType, rhs: YourType) -> Bool
```