# Find if user is already displayed in TableView using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm coding a viewController which permit to search specifics users. I have a searchBar and a listener:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
      doSearch()
}

func doSearch() {
      if let searchText = searchBar.text?.lowercased() {
         self.users.removeAll()
         self.tableView.reloadData()
         Api.User.queryUsers(withText: searchText, completion: { (user) in
               self.users.append(user)
               self.tableView.reloadData()
         })
      }
}
```

The queryUser func:

```
func queryUsers(withText text: String, completion: @escaping (Userm) -> Void) {
      REF_USERS.queryOrdered(byChild: "username_lowercase").queryStarting(atValue: text).queryEnding(atValue: text+"\u{f8ff}").queryLimited(toLast: 5).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
         snapshot.children.forEach({ (s) in
            let child = s as! DataSnapshot
            if let dict = child.value as? [String: Any] {
               let user = Userm.transformUser(dict: dict, key: child.key)
               completion(user)
            }
         })
      }
}
```

The problem is that, with Firebase, when I write too fast I can have the same user displayed several times. I would like to have a function which can do something like this:

```
// if user is not already contained in the array
-> Display it
```

I tried to use the .contains() function but I have not arrived at a good result, I'm still a beginner in Swift.

Do you have any idea please?

Comment: I found a topic which respond to my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330056/how-to-throttle-search-based-on-typing-speed-in-ios-uisearchbar I tried your answers but it didn't worked well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to filter the array the TableView uses to display data. This can be done either by casting it to a `Set` (since Sets only contain unique values) and then back to an `Array` again, or with an extension to the User class so it conforms to the `Equatable` protocol. Using the set option can be done like this:

```
let array = ["one", "one", "two", "two", "three", "three"]
let unique = Array(Set(array))
// ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Using the protocol would look something like this:

```
extension User: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    //make sure the User class has something that can uniquely identify them.
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `filters` to get a valid array.

something like this:

```
var someObject:SomeObject = receivedObjectFromMars
var arrayOfObjects:Array<SomeObject> = [object1, object2, object3, object4]
// imagine that 'someObject' has the same email of object1 and object 4.
var filteredArray:Array<String> = [];

filteredArray = arrayOfObjects.filter({ (obj) -> Bool in
    //so when you filter the array, you will compare a specific
    // attribute (e.g: email)
    return obj.email != someObject.email
})

// current filteredArray = [object2, object3]
```

So, after that, if you want to add the specific element, you just add.

```
filteredArray.append(someObject);
```

You can use it with other types, like strings, int, whatever.

get help here, too: [Swift 3 filter array of objects with elements of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267827/swift-3-filter-array-of-objects-with-elements-of-array)

JLU.