# How to filter an array based on some or all of the contents of a second array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I am attempting to filter an array based on the contents of a second array. Each element of the first array should be tested against all elements in the second array.

I have tested the following and I can get the filter to work just for the selected index i.e. 0.

```
var analysisArray = [String]()
var patternNameArray = [String]()

let filteredArray = analysisArray.filter {$0.isEmpty == false && $0.contains(patternNameArray[0])}
```

I tried the following based on [Swift 3 filter array of objects with elements of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267827/swift-3-filter-array-of-objects-with-elements-of-array)

```
let filteredArray = analysisArray.filter {$0.isEmpty == false && $0.contains(where: { patternNameArray.contains($0) })}
```

but I get an error "Extraneous argument label 'where:' in call".

How do I iterate over all the elements in the second array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the func **contains** on **$0** which is an element of **patternArray**, which is a **String**. The signature of the contains func for String is this:

`public func contains(where predicate: (Character) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool`

You are passing it a closure as you are, if I read things correctly, looking to call **contains** on an array.

I think that you are simply confusing the placeholders in the closure. If you are trying to achieve what I think you are, it could look like this:

```
import Foundation

var analysisArray = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Balloon", "Kite"]
var patternNameArray = ["oo", "ll"]

let filteredArray = analysisArray.filter { analysisString in
    analysisString.isEmpty == false &&
        patternNameArray.contains { pattern in
            analysisString.contains(pattern)
        }
}

print(filteredArray) // ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Balloon"]
```

I've expanded it a bit for brevity (never a bad thing when coding) so that it's a little clearer which closure variables are being used where. The output of this playground is ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Balloon"] which is each string in the analysisArray that contains one of the patters in the patternNameArray.

Hopefully I've read your question correctly.

Comment: That is correct. I was looking to call **contains** on the array. Your code works perfectly!